# Emqx : Miss a lot message that pushed by mqtt protocol

Tags: node.js, mqtt, emq

I am using mqtt protocol to push some message and my broker is emqx .I write this script by nodejs to push 200,000 message on specific topic:

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');

const options = {
    clientId: "tazikpush",
    clean: true
}
const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xxxxxxxxxx", options);
var topic = "/ApplyData/";
var pushOptions = {
    retain: false,
    qos: 2
}; 
const snooze = ms => new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));

const example = async () => {
    console.log('Waiting 5 sec and then start');
    await snooze(5000);
    for (var i = 0; i < 200000; i++) {
        // await snooze(250);
        client.publish(topic, message, pushOptions);
        console.log(`done! ${i}`);
    }
};
example();
```

and by nodejs i write a subscriber to listen on this topic and then store data into redis database.
But i have a problem about:

> Why listener should stop till push client push all 200000 message?
>
> Why subscriber just receive 100 message? and other message dropped.

On my subscriber i create a js file.In this file i create a client and subscribe on my topic with qos 2
**mqttClient.js**

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt');
const log4js = require('log4js');
const config = require('config');

const topic_sub = "/ApplyData/";
log4js.configure(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(config.get('Logger'))));
var logger = log4js.getLogger('app');
logger.level = 'debug';


const options = {
    clientId: "mqttjs01",
    clean: true
}

const client = mqtt.connect("mqtt://xxxxxxx", options);

client.on("connect", () => {
    console.log("connected  " + client.connected);
    client.subscribe(topic_sub, { qos: 2 });
});

client.on("error", (error) => {
    console.log("Can't connect" + error);
    logger.debug(`Client Error : `, error);
});


module.exports = client;
```

And i use client event on my controller . my subscriber actually is a worker, means it's job is just subscribe message and store these messages and store to database.

In App.js i require:

```
const client = require('./mqttClient');
const controller = require('./controller/mainController');
```

and in main Controller i subscribe messages with call `client.on`:

```
client.on('message', async (topic, message, packet) => {
        console.log(topic);
        if (topic === '/ApplyData/') {
            var jobject = JSON.parse(message);
            jobject.nid = uuid()
            try {
                let res = await redis_cache.cache(jobject);
            } catch (err) {
                console.log(err);
            }
```

I debug broker with running from console after pushing 200,000 messages i got

```
2019-09-25 11:41:50.885 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 36998 for too many awaiting_rel
2019-09-25 11:41:50.900 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 36999 for too many awaiting_rel
2019-09-25 11:41:50.900 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 37000 for too many awaiting_rel
2019-09-25 11:41:50.900 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 37001 for too many awaiting_rel
2019-09-25 11:41:50.900 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 37002 for too many awaiting_rel.... 
2019-09-25 11:49:57.544 [warning] tazikpush [Session] Dropped qos2 packet 40292 for too many awaiting_rel
2019-09-25 11:49:57.544 [warning] tazikpush [Session] The PUBREL PacketId 36898 is not found
2019-09-25 11:49:57.544 [warning] tazikpush [Session] The PUBREL PacketId 36899 is not found
2019-09-25 11:49:57.544 [warning] tazikpush [Session] The PUBREL PacketId 36900 is not found
2019-09-25 11:49:57.544 [warning] tazikpush [Session] The PUBREL PacketId 36901 is not found ...
```

log

Comment: Edit the question to include the where you actually subscribe to the topic

Comment: I updated my post dude @hardillb

Comment: It might help to update the question with regards broker you are using

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your publish is too fast and using a single client to handle consumption is too slow.

This may be related to your config:

`etc/emqx.conf`

```sh
## Maximum QoS2 packets (Client -> Broker) awaiting PUBREL, 0 means no limit.
##
## Value: Number
zone.external.max_awaiting_rel = 100

## The QoS2 messages (Client -> Broker) will be dropped if awaiting PUBREL timeout.
##
## Value: Duration
zone.external.await_rel_timeout = 300s
```

The best way is to use EMQ X Enterprise or share subscriptions to add more clients:

https://docs.emqx.io/tutorial/v3/en/advanced/share_subscribe.html